# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Member.add_roles' was never awaited member.add_roles(randomuser, randomcolors)

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a system where it takes a random online member from the server that doesn't have the roles in mods and it takes a random role from colors and gives it to the random member. but I keep getting this error:

> RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Member.add_roles' was never awaited
>   member.add_roles(randomuser, randomcolors) RuntimeWarning: Enable
>   tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

```
@client.command(name="sortearcolor")
@commands.has_any_role("DUEÑOS", "CO-OWNER", "Admin", "ADMIN", "Dev Discord+", "MOD", "MOD+", "Trial MOD", "Dev Discord")
async def _sorteocolor(ctx):
    online = []
    colors = ["Negro (Personalizado)", "Rosa (Ultra)", "Rosa-1 (Personalizado)",
    "Rosa-2 (Personalizado)", "Violeta (Ultra)", "Violeta (Personalizado)",
    "Morado (Personalizado)", "Celeste(Perso.)", "Violeta Brillante (Personalizado)",
    "Aqua (Personalizado)", "Amarillo-1 (Personalizado)", "Amarillo (Personalizado)",
    "Celesroide (Personalizado)", "Celeste (Personalizado)",
    "Azul-1 (Personalizado)", "Azul (Personalizado)", "Azul (Generico)",
    "Morado (Personalizado)", "Rosa pastel"]
    mods = ["Admin", "ADMIN", "Dev Discord+", "MOD", "MOD+", "Trial MOD", "Dev Discord"]

    for member in client.get_all_members():
        if str(member.status) == "online":
            for roles in ctx.guild.roles:
                if roles.name in mods:
                    pass 
                else:
                    online.append(str(member))
    randomuser = random.choice(online)
    randomcolors = random.choice(colors)
    member.add_roles(randomuser, randomcolors)
    await ctx.send(f"User: **{randomuser}**, Role: **{randomcolors}**")
```

it sends the message user: user, role: role though, but is not giving the user the role, I guess it has to do with the error message I'm getting. Also, it still picks members with the roles in mods, not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

In discord.py, you must use `await` before doing "action" commands. Just like you used `await` when you send the message to the channel, you must `await` adding the roles as well. Try doing, `await member.add_roles(randomuser, randomcolors)`

Comment: I get discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=add_roles#discord.Member.add_roles ... `member.add_roles` gives that member the role(s). If you want to give it to the `randomuser`, do randomuser.add_roles, then look at the documentation for the parameters it takes.

Comment: it says randomuser doesn't have the attribute add_roles. I'm sorry to bother you with this and I appreciate  your help. I've been trying to figure this out all day.